# Can you say "rancoring"?

Tags: grammaticality

I know it's an adjective, but I googled it, and found it in an article about John McEnroe, specifically, "a rancoring go-to-hell beast".

I was wondering if it is okay to use the word as if it were a verb?

Comment: There's no such word and the quote should have used rancorous.

Comment: Look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Tony1/Noun_plus_-ing

Comment: It's hard to understand why the writer insisted on using _rancoring_ when he or she could instead have used _queruling_.

Answer (score -1):

It's perfectly ok to use  *rancoring* as suggested in the quote, if one doesn't care whether listeners or readers understand, or if one is willing to risk being laughed at.  (That is, *rancoring* has a rather clumsy tone.  Like *rancoring*, *saddle-burring* would be an ad hoc construction, but it seems to me less clumsy.)

The adjectival form of noun *[rancor](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rancor#Noun)* is *[rancorous](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rancorous#Adjective)*, but “a rancorous go-to-hell beast” puts less emphasis on the subject's role in causing rancor than does “a rancoring go-to-hell beast”.

Terms like *rancorous* and *[abrasive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abrasive#Adjective)* (“Being rough and coarse in manner or disposition; causing irritation”) usually would be used rather than *rancoring*.  *[Irritating](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/irritating#Adjective)* and *[festering](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/festering)* would emphasize the subject's role slightly more, but *irritating* is weak and *festering* might be misunderstood.  Phrasing like  “a rough-tongued go-to-hell beast” might well work best.